# Lenovo ThinkPad T590 Integrated Camera doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, thinkpad, camera

My problem described in the title, I've googled for it for two evenings, but can do nothing with issue.

```
$uname -a

Linux thinkpad 5.0.0-36-generic #39~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 11:09:50 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e34 (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0b)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df9 (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9ded (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 9def (rev 30)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df0 (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9de8 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9de0 (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db8 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9dbc (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db0 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d84 (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9dc8 (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9da3 (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9da4 (rev 30)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V (rev 30)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
04:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
3a:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 15c1 (rev 01)
3c:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1d13 (rev a1)
3d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 011a
```

```
$lsusb

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices  # also tried with sudo, same result


Failed to open /dev/video0: No such file or directory
```

`lsmod | grep uvcvideo` command shows nothing, but when I plug external camera with USB, uvcvideo module loads and external camera works fine in both the cheese and webcamoid applications.

If I load `uvcvideo` with `modprobe` command still nothing happens.

```
$ sudo modprobe uvcvideo

$ lsmod | grep uvcvideo
uvcvideo               94208  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       45056  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              204800  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
media                  53248  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common

$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Failed to open /dev/video0: No such file or directory
```

It looks like integrated camera just disabled or something like that, so I've checked if camera is enabled in BIOS and yes, it's enabled.

Also it's sad, but I don't remember if I've checked camera on Windows before Linux install, but actually I doubt if it could be broken.

Maybe somebody knows what should I do to bring the camera to life?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] the output of `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` into your question. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek I've updated the question, but it's just "no such file or directory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information provided, it doesn't appear that your HD 720p webcam is functional and connected to the system. What can you do? Since this appears to be a hardware problem there's nothing magical you can do with software to make it function. However, if you are technically proficient you can open the bezel and confirm continuity between the camera and the board and restore it if it doesn't exist. if there is continuity through the connection, the fault is either with the camera board or perhaps the board it connects to You can find replacement parts for your Lenovo Thinkpad T590 [here.](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/partslookup) You can change your country/region and language at the top of the page as shown below:

[image: lenovo support]

Comment: Thanks, I think you're absolutely right and it's hardware problem

Comment: @elder-geek I have a very similar problem but the major difference is I do have /dev/video0 (same model etc, but updated to Ubuntu 20.04.1) I can see inside of dmesg that the integrated camera can be seen but when I open VLC or cheese all I get is a blank screen... any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @Reuben-devries Since your problem is different I suggest you ask a new question. This. Question can be used as an example of what information you should provide. Cheers!

Comment: I figured it out, it was a problem between the keyboard and the chair.

Comment: @ReubendeVries I'm glad you got your PICNIC problem sorted out. Cheers!